# Web API with social.following

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, social, following

I would like to create a Web API which interacts with the SocialFollowManager. I want to be able to make a document unfollowed. The exposed Web Api will be later accessed by a mobile application.

Does anyone done that and if yes could you point me to some examples?

Answer (score 1):

**Endpoint URI structure**

```
POST http://<siteCollection>/<site>/_api/social.following/stopfollowing
```

**Request parameter**

actor

Type: `SP.Social.SocialActorInfo`

The actor to stop following.

**Document actor in the URI**

```
http://<siteCollection>/<site>/_api/social.following/stopfollowing(ActorType=1,ContentUri=@v,Id=null)?@v='http://server/Shared%20Documents/fileName.docx'
```

**Document actor in the request body**

JSON:

```
"actor":{
  "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"},
  "ActorType":1,
  "ContentUri":"http://server/Shared%20Documents/fileName.docx",
  "Id":null
}
```

**JavaScript example**

```
var webUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
stopFollowing(webUrl,'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx')
    .done(function(data){
       console.log('Document stopped following');
    });


function stopFollowing(webUrl,fileUrl){
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/social.following/stopfollowing";
    var actor = {
         "actor":{
             "__metadata":{"type":"SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"},
             "ActorType":1,
             "ContentUri":fileUrl,
             "Id":null
          }
    };         
    return executeRequest(endpointUrl,'POST',null,actor);
}
```

where

```
function executeRequest(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    if (typeof headers == 'undefined' || headers == null){
        headers = {};
    }
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }   

    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if(method == "POST") {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  

    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

### References

[Following people and content REST API reference for SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn194080%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bk_StopFollowing)